# Cell formula to cell values for different range

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am new to Excel vba.. I need to create a macro for below situation.

`R12=(Q12/P12)/2 Q12=40 P12=20`

I need to show the `R12` cell like `(40-20)/2`.
I have a some different spreadsheets. So the input is selected by user by mouse. That all selcted rows must convert to values from formulae.

Please help me

Comment: What have you tried?
this is not a place to beg for code/get a whole solution..

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear whether your formula is R12=(Q12/P12)/2 or R12=(Q12-P12)/2. So accordingly change your formula as required.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim input1, input2, result As Variant
    input1 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select first cell", Title:="Cell Select", Type:=8)
    input2 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select second cell", Title:="Cell Select", Type:=8)
    result = (input1 - input2) / 2
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = result
End Sub
```